# HTML wrapping when resizing a browser

Tags: html, css

Could someone explain to me how to use CSS to enable word wrapping when decreasing the size of my browser? I tried doing `word-wrap: break-word;`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please try and explain more about what the problem is exactly that you're having. If possible show us your code and/or create a working example of your problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Read this article http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previous answer was not correct this code should now work for you. i have tested this here: http://jsfiddle.net/nHuBk/ You will also need to set a width of how ever large you want the wrap to be:

```
div {
width: 200px; //or what ever size you want
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```